# Set wire + draw all edges on as default

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

Is there a way to enable wire and draw all edges in Object -> Display as default?
So I don't have to enable it for every single object.

[image]

Any help is appreciated! :D

Comment: Not possible atm, afaik. You can set "scene" default properties saving a custom startup file, but not objects properties. It would be handy, anyway.

Comment: Damn, it would be handy indeed.

Comment: You can just select all objects and enable desired option, e.g. Wire, with `Alt` pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the "Copy Attributes" add-on. [Here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Copy_Attributes_Menu)

This add-on allows you to copy alot more things to objects than with just the "ctrl+L" hotkey in blender. It also allows you to copy "Draw Options" of the selected object to the others with "ctrl+c".